# How to open Chosen via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-chosen

I need to open the [Chosen dropdown](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) via JavaScript so users do not have to click on the select to show it, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem,

just make sure chzn-select is the ID of your select.

chzn-drop will stay opened after users click on an option:

```
        $('#chzn-select').change(function(event)
        {
            $('.chzn-drop').css('left', 0);
        });
```

Comment: This is wrong since it doesn't add "active" classes' set to Chosen's markup. Techfoobar gave you a nice hint - "click" event would be more suitable to use in this situation though.

Comment: It works, I just checked it. Remember that you must trigger a click event on an anchor that resides in main container (.chzn-container > .chzn-single).

Answer (score 18):

You can open a *chosen* select box via JS by doing:

```
$('#<id-of-your-select>_chzn').trigger('mousedown');
```

where `<id-of-your-select>` is the id of your `<select>` element.

For ex: if your `<select>` element is like `<select id="foo" ...>`, then the code above will become:

```
$('#foo_chzn').trigger('mousedown');
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this doesnt work for me for:
<select name="chzn-select[]" id="chzn-select" data-placeholder="<?php echo _("click.to.select.tags")?>" style="width:350px; direction: rtl" multiple
                                    class="chzn-select-create-option chzn-rtl"  tabindex="8">

The JS code is: 
<input type="button" onclick="console.log($('#chzn-select_chzn').trigger('mousedown'));" value="ClicktoOpen">

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out forever.

Comment: You are rocks awesome!

Comment: `$("#<id-of-your-select>+div')` should work accross versions since they do seem to change the id suffix

Answer (score 13):

It is very weird but i find answer is using timeout

it somehow neet to timeout first
maybe because my element is cloned
hope useful for others

```
setTimeout(function(){ firstElement.trigger("chosen:open"); }, 100);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can add the below two lines to your code it will keep your chosen always open. It worked for me.

`list_start` is your select element id.

```
("#list_start").trigger('chosen:open');
$('.chosen-drop').css('left', 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

In the updated [Chosen jquery plugin](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) following works fine with stopPropagation.

```js
$("#selectbox").trigger("chosen:open");   
event.stopPropagation();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectbox").chosen({});
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#selectbox").trigger("chosen:open");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
#selectbox {
  width: 140px
}
```

```html
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>


<select id="selectbox">
  <option val="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option val="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option val="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option val="option5">Option 5</option>
  <option val="option6">Option 6</option>
</select>


<button>Trigger Chosen</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

@tzvi's answer is valuable in the in the event that you're trying to trigger chosen so that it stays open after a selection is made (IE: making multiple selections in one go). Allow me to extend this a bit (updated for chosen 1.0, by the way):

```
$('#selectbox').change(function() {
  $('#selectbox_chosen .chosen-drop').css('left', '0');
});

$('html').click(function() {
  $('#selectbox_chosen .chosen-drop').css('left', '');
});

$('#selectbox_chosen .chosen-drop').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Essentially it forces the chosen dropdown to stay open by overriding some css that is usually in place by the "active" class. Then we have a couple of click events that will undo this if you click anywhere outside off the dropdown. Worked perfectly for me.

Edit:
By the way, if you really want to trigger the drop down via JS, use Chosen 1.0's API:

```
$('#selectbox').trigger('chosen:open')
```

In context of the original question, this will allow you to open the box or reopen the box after a selection is made. It will not, however, keep the box open after a selection is made (without closing for a moment).